# How can I return to a specific GIT commit without miss any changes from that date to now?

Tags: git, commit, restore, rollback

I have a list of commits, I want to restore on of them, but without messing with the rest of the changes... I want to restore ONLY the changes made on that commit, can I?

Comment: What do you mean by "restore" ? Delete the modification made in a specific commit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are trying to reverse a commit which is some time before your current HEAD without reversing the commits afterwards.

To do so, use `git revert <commit>`

`git revert` creates a new commit that reverses the specified commit(s).

man page: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html